# Mudar o texto de acordo com a imagem do slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slide

Olá,

Estou mexendo com HTML/CSS, fui fazer um slide e me surgiu uma duvida, Provavelmente de JavaScript.

Fiz um mini slide de produtos em destaque, e do lado desse slide, tem o texto referente ao produto.
Tem alguma maneira de tratar o slide, para que quando a pessoa clica para mudar a imagem do slide, o texto mude junto com a imagem?

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div class="large-12 columns">
  <div class="w3-content" style="max-width:100%;position:relative; padding: 5px;">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-7 columns" style="margin-top: 50px;">
          <img class="mySlides" src="http://niderarep.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/logo-quero-grande.png" style="width:100%">
          <img class="mySlides" src="https://img.meutimao.com.br/_upload/forumtopico/2016/01/28/eduardo-jorge-quero.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <img class="mySlides" src="http://m.memegen.com/0ekn13.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <img class="mySlides" src="http://www.rstche.com.br/imagens/quero-quero.jpg" style="width:100%">

          <a class="w3-btn-floating" style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:0" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">❮</a>
          <a class="w3-btn-floating" style="position:absolute;top:50%;right:0px" onclick="plusDivs(1)">❯</a>
        </div>


        <div class="large-5 columns" style="margin-top: 50px;">
          <h3>Título produto em destaque</h3>

          <p style="line-height: 2.0;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <a href="http://www.wgmodelo.com.br/index.html">
            <button style="float:right; background: #000;">Saiba mais</button>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Grato desde de já.

Comment: poste um trecho do seu código, para podermos exemplificar pra vc!

Comment: Adicionei o trecho no post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você quis dizer "conteúdo", não "texto", certo? A melhor maneira de fazer isso é criando containers para cada imagem sequencialmente, que podem ser escondidos ou expandidos, como no seu código:

```
<div class="large-5 columns" style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <h3>Título produto em destaque</h3>
    ...
</div>
```

Com isso você pode dar uma classe nova para cada div, contendo um nome pré-fixo e o número da imagem à qual a `div` pertence.

Vamos supor que cada `div` vai ter a classe `image-[número]` e o `display: none`.

```
<div class="large-5 columns image-1" style="display: none; margin-top: 50px;">
    <h3>Conteúdo da primeira imagem</h3>
    ...
</div>

<div class="large-5 columns image-2" style="display: none; margin-top: 50px;">
    <h3>Conteúdo da segunda imagem</h3>
    ...
</div>

<div class="large-5 columns image-3" style="display: none; margin-top: 50px;">
    <h3>Conteúdo da terceira imagem</h3>
    ...
</div>

<div class="large-5 columns image-4" style="display: none; margin-top: 50px;">
    <h3>Conteúdo da quarta imagem</h3>
    ...
</div>
```

Agora, para mudar de conteúdo basta pegar a div com a classe `image-[slideIndex]` e definir a propriedade de estilo `display: block;`.

```
function showDivs(n) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

    if (n > x.length) slideIndex = 1;
    if (n < 1) slideIndex = x.length;

    for (var i = 0, len = x.length; i < len; i++) {

        x[i].style.display = "none";
        document.getElementsByClassName("image-" + (i + 1))[0].style.display = "none";

    }

    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    document.getElementsByClassName("image-" + slideIndex)[0].style.display = "block";
}
```

Outra solução é colocar cada `div` dentro de um container, mas ainda é mais seguro usar classes com pré-fixo porque a ordem dos elementos pode ser modificada no inspecionador de elementos.

Comment: Exatamente isso. Resolveu meu problema, criei os containers para cada imagem e realmente deu certo. Obrigado!!!!!